# Passing values from Django template to javascript-ajax function

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

Now my template displays a table having a link on each row to display more details. Each row passes unique `column_name`, `db_name`, `schema_name`, `tablenm` combination to get more details.

```
<td>
    <a href="{% url 'moreDetails' column_name=row.colname db_name=row.dbname schema_name=row.schemaname table_name=row.tablenm %} " target="_blank">
        Values
    </a>
</td>
```

The above code works , but open a new window for the result set. But, I would like to route it through a javascript(Jquery-django) and capture the result back in Javascript and display the result as a javascript message without refreshing the complete page.

How Can I pass there values (`column_name`, `db_name`, `schema_name`, `tablenm`) to the java script on the click event

I tried replacing href with button and set a value to it

```
<td>
    <input type="button" value={% row.colname |","| row.dbname |","| row.schemaname |","| row.tablenm %} class="apireq" />
<td>
```

But seems not working. I welcome any help on this . Thanks In advance

Comment: If you want to pass variables to javascript you either need to write the javascript in your template files or pass the variables to the javascript somehow from the template file. (Assign variables to the `window` or set data attributes of an element which JS can then read)

Comment: you can return JsonResponse with the data in your view, then use ajax to display the data, that way you don't have to refresh your browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not set them as data attributes?

```
<input type="button" class="apireq" 
       data-colname="{{row.colname}}"
       data-dbname="{{row.dbname}}"
       data-schemaname="{{row.schemaname}}"
       data-tablenm="{{row.tablenm}}"
/>
```

Then in your click event handler you will have a reference to the button that generated the event, all you need to to is read the attributes off of it. And they are already parsed out so no worries there too.

Comment: Thanks . I am quite new to jquery .. I tried the following . But didn't work . Appreciate any help

Comment: I added a <tbody id="collist"></tbody> above the table data and trying to get that data in java script like , var jq_column_name=  $("#collist tr").last().attr("data-colname"); . But not working .It says jq_column_name value "undefined" . Thanks

Comment: var jq_column_name = $(this).attr('data-colname'); worked . Thanks